# Tensorboard not loading unless I swap port each time

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tensorboard

I am trying to view my training process in tensorboard I have two main problems:

- Often the jupyter interactive window (in VSCODE) often does not display anything when i run `%tensorboard --logdir fullpath --host localhost --port 6969`
- When I visit http://localhost:6969/ it often fails to load or on occasion shows no logs present

When I change the port to 6006 and reload it will work sometimes. But even still the notebook remains blank. Is there a reason for this?